# How to find the birth month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Given the following data sample:

```
ID Dob

001 01/10/1997
002 09/02/1983
003 19/10/1978
....
```

I tried a query like this:

```
select id, dob
  from table1
  where dob between '10/01/2012' and '10/31/2012'
```

But I am not retrieving any records. I want to display the id and dob matching with month.

Expected output:

```
ID dob

001 01/10/1997
003 19/10/1978
....
```

I would like the output to match the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the month() function, which  retrieves the month number for a given date

see [MSDN LINK HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

```
Select id, dob
from   table1
where  month(dob) =10
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9bd9f/3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx).

```
where month(Dob) = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DATEPART()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
Select id, dob
from yourTable 
where datepart(month, dob) = 10
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7420/1)